# How to get rid of ido-find-file

Tags: key-bindings

I have recently switched from obsolete ibuffer-mode to ido mode, and it replaced `C-x C-f` command to ido-find-file with completions. I don't need it. How to revert it back to simple `find-file`?

I tried to set in configs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'find-file)
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: *Workaround:* when in `ido-find-file`, press `C-f` to drop back to `find-file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete the remap alist entry from `ido-minor-mode-map-entry`. To do that, run the function below once after enabling `ido-mode`.

```
(defun disable-ido-find-file-remap ()
  (interactive)
    (dolist (elt ido-minor-mode-map-entry)
      (when (and (listp elt) (eq (car elt) 'remap))
        (setf (cddr elt) (assq-delete-all 'find-file (cddr elt))))))
```

I looked at the source file `ido.el` to write that function.

*Remark:* if you press `C-f` while in `ido-find-file`, you can use `find-file` (without using my above function).